# Cassandra table design for query with ORDER, LIMIT and IN predicate

Tags: sql, database-design, cassandra, cql

I have data that looks like:

```
select * from test;

 department | employee | batch_number | hash
------------+----------+--------------+-------
 dep1       | Bart     |            1 | hash1
 dep1       | Bart     |            1 | hash2
 dep1       | Lisa     |            3 | hash3
 dep1       | Lisa     |            4 | hash4
 dep1       | John     |            5 | hash5
 dep1       | Lucy     |            6 | hash6
 dep1       | Bart     |            7 | hash7
 dep1       | Bart     |            7 | hash8
```

And I would like to query the data with a `where` clause on `batch_number`, an `ordering` on `batch_number` and an `in` predicate on `employee`.

In a relational database this would look like

```
select * from test 
  where department='dep1' 
  and employee in ('Bart','Lucy','John') 
  and batch_number >= 2 
  order by batch_number desc 
  limit 3;

 department | employee | batch_number | hash
------------+----------+--------------+-------
 dep1       | Bart     |            7 | hash7
 dep1       | Bart     |            7 | hash8
 dep1       | Lucy     |            6 | hash6
```

I'm having some issues modelling a table for this query in Cassandra. `department` will be my partition key and `hash` needs to be part of the primary key. But I'm struggling with cluster keys and/or ((SSTable attached) secondary) indexes.

Because I want ordering on `batch_number` I tried including it as a cluster key:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.test(
    department      TEXT,
    batch_number    INT,
    hash            TEXT,
    employee        TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((department), batch_number, hash)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (batch_number DESC);
CREATE INDEX tst_emp ON keyspace.test (employee);
```

But this does not allow for queries with an `in` predicate on my index:

```
select * from keyspace.test where department='dep1' and employee in ('Bart','Lucy','John');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (employee) is not yet supported"
```

So I tried adding the `employee` column as cluster key as well:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.test(
    department      TEXT,
    batch_number    INT,
    hash            TEXT,
    employee        TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((department), batch_number, hash, employee)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (batch_number DESC);
```

But this fails because I can not put a non-EQ relation on `batch_number`:

```
select * from keyspace.test where department='dep1' and batch_number > 1 and employee in ('Bart','Lucy','John');
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering column "employee" cannot be restricted (preceding column "batch_number" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"
```

But whenever I put `employee` before `batch_number` I lose the ability to order on `batch_number`:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.test(
    department      TEXT,
    employee        TEXT,
    batch_number    INT,
    hash            TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((department), employee, batch_number, hash)
);

select * from keyspace.test where department='dep1' and employee in ('Bart','Lucy','John') ORDER BY batch_number DESC;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY"
```

So what table design would allow for such a query?
Can this be done in Cassandra?

**Edit:**

Other queries I would like to be able to run on this table are:

```
select * from keyspace.test where department='X' and batch_number=Y
```

and

```
delete from keyspace.test where department='X'
```

Comment: Why do you want to partition on department? In Cassandra, design is influenced by the queries, and these queries would work better if you could partition on employee.

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson The other queries I need to be able to do besides the one in the question are  `select * from keyspace.test where department='X' and batch_number=Y` and `delete from keyspace.test where department='X'` So because 'department' is what all my queries have in common, I figured it would serve me best as partition key.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 3):

Using a materialized view that allows you to rearrange your data:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test AS 
SELECT
   department,
   batch_number,
   employee,
   hash 
FROM
   test 
WHERE
   department IS NOT NULL 
   AND batch_number IS NOT NULL 
   AND employee IS NOT NULL 
   AND hash IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (department, employee, batch_number, hash) 
WITH clustering 
ORDER BY
(batch_number DESC);
```

I can perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mv_test 
WHERE
   department = 'dep1' 
   AND employee IN 
   (
      'Bart',
      'Lisa'
   )
   AND batch_number > 3;
```

The results are ordered due to the clustering order:

```
 department | employee | batch_number | hash
------------+----------+--------------+-------
       dep1 |     Bart |            7 | hash7
       dep1 |     Bart |            7 | hash8
       dep1 |     Lisa |            4 | hash4
```

While `>` clauses are non-equal clauses, `IN`, while having multiple values, is still deterministic, which is why I believe you can filter the keys without issue. 
Since `batch_number` is the last thing you want to filter, any type of where clause is allowed. I am assuming that you always have `department`.

Note that materialized views [impact performance](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/materialized-view-performance-in-cassandra-3-x). More specifically, write performance. However it is beneficial to read performance as opposed to `ALLOW FILTERING`.

**UPDATE:**

The ordering specified at the end of the materialized view says `batch_number`, however, it will first order on `department`, then `employee`, and then `batch_number`, so the order of the `batch_number` specifically is not guaranteed. As far as I know there is no way around this. Another database solution may be preferable.

**UPDATE 2:**

As stated in an Apache mailing chain (see comments below), materialized views are not deemed production-ready. However, Datastax considers them usable, provided they are taken care of using the mentioned best practices. Personally, I have not had any trouble with materialized views. This is of course, with a simple single datacenter cluster and considering the best practices mention more complicated setups, they could break in such circumstances.

Comment: DON'T use Materialized Views!!! They are not production ready/stable, up to the point that they were pulled back and put on experimental mode.

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201710.mbox/%3CetPan.59f24f38.438f4e99.74dc@apple.com%3E

Comment: @PedroGordo I would think that production readiness is irrelevant as opposed to possibility. Which is what was asked. Since this is indeed a viable answer to the question asked, I would ask you to remove your downvote. Additionally, I'd like to refer to the first question of this Datastax FAQ: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/faqMV.html

Comment: That works, even if I think it should be made more explicit. :) I've seen some major s***storms because of MVs. And they can give you a slow cooking catastrophe... But anyway, as promised, downvote removed ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index on the `employee` and even remove it from the primary key if you want. You would need to drop the use of `IN` but you could split the query and join the results on the client side.

```
CREATE TABLE tk.test_good(
    department      TEXT,
    batch_number    INT,
    employee        TEXT,
    hash            TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((department), batch_number, hash)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (batch_number DESC);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS employee_idx ON tk.test_good ( employee );

select * from tk.test_good where department='dep1' and employee='Bart' and batch_number >= 2 limit 3;
select * from tk.test_good where department='dep1' and employee='Lucy' and batch_number >= 2 limit 3;
select * from tk.test_good where department='dep1' and employee='John' and batch_number >= 2 limit 3;
```

The downside of this approach is that your indexes might get too big. But I don't know the data pool size, so I'll leave that at your consideration.

Comment: Your solution does not order the results on `batch_number`. They are ordered on `employee`. The ***first*** ordering criteria should be `batch_number` in my use case. My query will look like `select * from keyspace.test where department='dep1' and employee in ('Bart','Lucy','John') and batch_number >= 2 limit 3;`

Comment: You're right, of course. I meant to say that the batch_number would come ordered after each employee record (but still not ordered as a stand-alone). Is batch_number higher in hierarchy to the employee?

Comment: For ordering, the `batch_number` is indeed higher in hierarchy. The idea is that the query would return records for a batch number that's higher than a specific value (2 in my example) ***and*** be ordered/limited by newest first (i.e. `batch_number DESC`).

Comment: @MaartenDhondt check if the updated solution works for you.

Comment: The updated solution does work but I'm not really satisfied with it because the number of employees in my initial `IN` predicate will not actually be 3, but something like 15 or 20. So that would mean that with this sollution I'd have to query the db 20 times. Throw all the results together in my backend and resort it all just to discard up to 95% of the querried results. By the way the number of records will most likely be less than a million. Is that too big for the index you think?

Comment: True. It's not pretty. Anyways, I'm going to follow this question as I'm curious what other solutions people will come up with.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt sorry, I just saw your last question now. It's difficult to say what's the impact of cardinality, without looking at the final size of the index. Thinking in generic terms, I would say that a million is already too much. Have you tried it out? What was the index size?